# How to construct i.i.d. standard normal random variables on $\Omega = [0, 1]$ with the Lebesgue measure

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, real-analysis

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be the unit interval with Lebesgue measure on the Borel subsets. Then we can find independent random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots$ defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, each normal mean zero, variance $1$.

This is a special case of the Borel isomorphism theorem, but I was wondering if anyone could supply/refer me to a proof which does not invoke it, since it seems like overkill here. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we can find independent random variables $U_j$ uniform on $[0,1]$ we can transform them to $\mathcal N(0,1)$.  If $Y$ is uniform on $[0,1]$, let $D_j$ be its $j$'th decimal place, i.e. $Y = \sum_{j=1}^\infty 10^{1-j} D_j$ with 
$D_j \in \{0,1,\ldots, 9\}$.  If $p_j$ is the $j$'th prime, let
$U_j = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 10^{1-k} D_{p_j^k}$.  Then $U_j$ are iid uniform on $[0,1]$.

Comment: As to how to transform them to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, let $\Phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}\,dx$ be the normal cdf, and set $X_j = \Phi^{-1}(U_j)$.

Comment: @NateEldredge and of course there's nothing special about the normal distribution here: For any desired output distribution with cdf $F$, we can set $X = F^{-1}(U)$. (Hope this comment is not overly pedantic...)

Comment: @usul: Indeed.  Though a little more work is needed if $F$ is not strictly increasing, i.e. not 1-1.